# python variable not accessable in a function

Tags: python, tkinter

i have this variable outside of my function and when i try to modify it inside the function ther's just a new variable defined inside the function.

```
accessPath = ""

def AccessButton_Func():
    text=filedialog.askopenfile().name
    if not text == None: 
        accessPath = text
        AccessLabel.configure(text=text)
```

my function is used in a tkinter button and there's no return for it.

i tried using a global variable but that does not work with other functions i have.

Answer (score 2):

`To modify a global variable inside a function, you need to use the global keyword to indicate that you want to modify the global variable, rather than creating a new local variable with the same name

```
def AccessButton_Func():
    global accessPath  
    text = filedialog.askopenfile().name
    if text:
       accessPath = text  
       AccessLabel.configure(text=text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using **global** keyword in order to change your variable from the function scope:

```
accessPath = ""

def AccessButton_Func():
    global accessPath # <-------------------- HERE

    text=filedialog.askopenfile().name
    if not text == None: 
        accessPath = text
        AccessLabel.configure(text=text)
```